How to capture Tab + Escap key combinations in angular?
When the user pressed Tab + Escape key then I wanted to call my function but I couldn't capture this combination. If this combination is not possible then I want one combination with Escape key but those combination are not used in Windows, Ubuntu and Mac.
I tried like this:
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
async onkeyDown($event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if($event.key === 'Tab' && $event.code === 'Escape') {
    console.log('Tab + Escape keys pressed');  
  }
} 

I want to capture Tab + Escape key combination.

For shift and ctrl keys, HTML provide a convenient event.ctrlKey and event.shiftKey attached to the event (click event for example for ctrl + click)..
For the 'Tab' key you don't have such mechanic, but as you can still detect any keystroke, you can do something like this:
// Store variables

tabPressed: boolean = false;
escapePressed: boolean = false;

// Handle tab key

@HostListener("document:keydown.tab", ["$event"])
onTabKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
  this.tabPressed = true;
  console.log("Tab pressed");
  if (this.escapePressed && this.tabPressed) {
    // Both are pressed
  }
}

@HostListener("document:keyup.tab", ["$event"])
onTabKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
  this.tabPressed = false;
  console.log("Tab no longer pressed"); 
}

// Handle escape key

@HostListener("document:keydown.escape", ["$event"])
onEscapeKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
  this.escapePressed = true;
  console.log("Escape pressed");
  if (this.escapePressed && this.tabPressed) {
    // Both are pressed
  }
}

@HostListener("document:keyup.escape", ["$event"])
onEscapeKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
  this.escapePressed = false;
  console.log("Escape no longer pressed");
}

Hope this helps!
PS: Those listeners does not have to be async

Instead of using 'window:keydown' use 'document:keydown'. Afterwards you can handle combinations of keys pressed on the keyboard. For example by using event.keyCode.
Furthermore, you could directly listen on escape-key-presses with 'window:keydown.escape'.
